# Docker server side information not returned when running `docker version`

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, docker, containers

I have today installed Docker on my Ubuntu 16.04 PC, it is a dell XPS15. The client side works well, but if I launch:

```
docker version
```

It returns a `permission denied` error:

```
Client:
Version:   17.12.1-ce
API version:   1.35
Go version:   go1.9.4
Git commit:   7390fc6
Built:   Tue Feb 27 22:17:40 2018
OS/Arch:   linux/amd64
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at 
unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get 
http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.35/version: dial unix 
/var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `sudo` -- you can look at user management under the docker docs to change it -- i don't think they recommend it though

Comment: @JavierBuzzi
Yeah it work!! 
thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The doc [has a chapter on running the client as a non-root user](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/), just follow the instructions and you should be good to go, so no need to type `sudo` every time :)

```
$ sudo groupadd docker
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Then logout from your user session and login back again and try `docker run hello-world`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, with sudo it work fine, now i try to add this permissions